# "Hello" and "sincerely" when writting letters

Tags: hebrew

*Not sure if this falls on the side/outside of the scope of this page. If so, let me know, and I can delete.*

---

I have heard of *shalom aleichem* among people and the reply *aleichem shalom*, or simply *shalom*.

Does one use this in letters, and then what? Typically in English tradition one could use for example:

> Dear Professor Adam Jack, | Dear Sir or Madam, | Hello, | etc.
>
> It is with great expectations …
>
> Sincerely, | Sincerely yours, | Best regards, | etc.
>   *John Doe*

Is it tradition to use Hebrew, when rest of text is in English, for letters as in for example:

> Shalom aleichem,
>
> It is with great expectations …
>
> Shalom,
>   *John Doe*

How does on start/end letters in this context?

Comment: @DanF, I didn't take this question to be asking whether it is strict protocol

Comment: My rav usually writes his letters in English and ends with "Bivracha" (with blessings) or "Beyedidut" (Fondly? - is that correct translation?) I'm not sure, though if that's his general ending or only to those who understand Hebrew :-) I think this format is common. What does somewhat annoy me is some of the "yeshivish" I get in the middle of the letters, as much of yeshivish is "corrupted" Hebrew. But, that's a different story o:-{

Comment: A great way to see what's a traditional start and end to a letter in the context of Judaism (for, after all, all question on this site are asking in the context of Judaism) is to look at volumes of _sh'elos us'shuvos_.

Comment: @msh210 , Rav Moshe : מעלת כבודו ידידי... and signed ידידו .